# how can i Auto reorder product when i choose only date of shipping in magento frontend?

Tags: php, magento

Users can re-order without the effort of re-ordering.
 Enter the date of every month when you want the products to be shipped in magento
 Any idea please ??
How can  i use reccurring magento ??

Comment: check this http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/working-with-recurring-profiles

Comment: thanks huzefam.. it will be helpfull for me !!!